# What is the default indent size?

Tags: paragraphs

When a paragraph begins, there is an indentation in the first line. How do I know the size of the indentation? Does it depend on the size of the font? Does it depend on something else?

Comment: The indentation amount is governed by the parameter `\parindent`. Various document classes will choose differing values. Type `\the\parindent` to print its current value.

Comment: @juanuni: `book.cls` and `article.cls` both use `20pt` as standard values. It's defined in `latex.ltx` (i.e. the LaTeX kernel)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it is set to 20pt in the format but (at 10pt option) article/report/book set it to 1em in two column and 15pt in one column.